# Update two tables using sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables to be updated. I will have to consider three tables as the

- field 'X' present in Table A is present in Table C
- field 'Y' present in Table B is present in Table C

So, I would like to update a column in Table A and Table B based on the condition

```
if TABLE A.X = TABLE C.X 
   AND TABLE B.Y = TABLE C.Y
```

Let me know how to proceed. As im a newbie not able to figure out how it can be coded

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question some sample data and the expected output. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Add sample table data, and also show us the updated versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update two tables in a single query. 
Write separate queries to update each table using the given condition.

If you are using `SQL Server`,Use the following scripts.

Update script for  table `TABLEA`

```
UPDATE t1
  SET t1.[ColumnYouWantedToUpdate]=[Value]
FROM TABLEA t1
   JOIN TABLEC t2 ON t1.X=t2.X
   JOIN TABLEB t3 ON t2.Y=t3.Y
```

Update script for  table `TABLEB`

```
  UPDATE t3
    SET t3.[ColumnYouWantedToUpdate]=[Value]
  FROM TABLEB t1
    JOIN TABLEC t2 ON t1.X=t2.X
    JOIN TABLEB t3 ON t2.Y=t3.Y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 -- maybe like this :)

  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
 update TABLE A set (--any field which an updated)
 where EXISTS
 (
 select * from TableA A inner join TableC C on A.X =C.X inner join
 TableB B on B.Y = C.Y
 )

 update TABLE B set (--any field which an updated)
 where EXISTS
 (
 select * from TableA A inner join TableC C on A.X =C.X inner join
 TableB B on B.Y = C.Y
  )
  COMMIT TRAN
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRAN
  END CATCH
```